# Expected Values of Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

[image]

Find $E(X^{2k-1})$  for $k = 1, 2, 3, 4, ...$

Find $E(X^{2k})$  for $k = 1, 2, 3, 4, ...$

I used the fact that:
$e^x = 1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} +....$ to get:

$e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} = 1+\frac{t^2}{2}+ \frac{{(\frac{t^2}{2})^2}}{2!} + \frac{{(\frac{t^2}{2})^3}}{3!} + \frac{{(\frac{t^2}{2})^4}}{4!} +....$.  I don't know how I use this information to solve for the expected values

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb E[X^k]=\left.\frac{\mathrm d ^k}{\mathrm d t^k}\right|_{t=0}M(t).$$

So, if $$M(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n,$$
then $$\mathbb E[X^k]=k!a_k.$$

Comment: So then would $E(X^{2k-1})$=(2k-1)!$a_{2k-1}$?

Comment: surb is this the correct idea?

Comment: Of course. Now, you have to compute the $a_{k}$ and conclude.